# How to center 90º rotated text in SVG

Tags: svg, d3.js

Working with D3, I want to have a Y axis label which is rotated -90º and centered on the Y axis.  I thought this would be a piece of cake, and wrote the following:

```
// Y Axis Label
svg.append('svg:text')
    .attr('class', 'y label')
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('y', 0)
    .attr('width', height)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(-' + yAxisSpacing + ',' + height + ') rotate(-90)')
    .text('Y Axis Label')
```

`height` in this case is the height of the chart (the vertical area occupied by svg).  The above code will render a `<text>` element to the bottom left of the chart, then center the text relative to that bottom left point.  The `width` does *not* change and thus instead of being centered it runs off the bottom left hand corner of the svg.

I had guessed that if the `width` was equal to the `height` of the chart, then the text within it would become vertically centered.  That doesn't seem to be the case -OR- there is some magic `display:block` type property I need to set in SVG in order for `width` to work on the `<text>` element.

How should this be done?

---

Based on the responses, I went with a javascript route and modified the above line to be (height/2)...

```
.attr('transform', 'translate(-' + yAxisSpacing + ',' + height / 2 + ') rotate(-90)')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `width` attribute has no effect on <text> in SVG 1.1. The text will be centered (due to text-anchor=middle) around the x,y position defined by the `x` and `y` attributes (they default to 0 if you don't specify them). After that the `transform` attribute is applied.

Comment: So in other words I have to manually set the transform x,y to vertically centered with javascript.  I was hoping to get away with a pure CSS solution which could be fluid with the page size.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with CSS transform. Add this to your CSS (via [http://css3please.com](http://css3please.com/)):

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
   -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); 
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); 
     -o-transform: rotate(90deg); 
        transform: rotate(90deg); 
           filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(/* IE6–IE9 */
                 M11=6.123031769111886e-17, M12=-1, M21=1, M22=6.123031769111886e-17, sizingMethod='auto expand');
             zoom: 1;
```

Working example here - look in the 'css' tab: http://livecoding.io/3492918

Comment: On the example the Y-axis label is rotated but isn't vertically centered, which is the part I was after.